# Extended desktops to two TVs, from laptops without HDMI outs

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm trying to achieve extended desktops from my laptop, to two (or more) tvs, in a professional way.

At its most basic, it would be as if I had two HDMI outs on my laptop going into the two TVs HDMI inputs.

Ideally, more than one laptop could extend its displays.

The laptops don't have HDMI outs, just ethernet ports.

I've been reading about HDMI over IP, but without any experience doing this, I'm not sure how it would all come together.

I've created a network diagram as a guide, however it references HDMI over Ethernet and the feedback I've got so far suggests it wouldn't work.

https://go.gliffy.com/go/share/sb4iuuvvdiu7rspmxam6

Is there a "right" way to do it?

I'm prepared to spend $200 if necessary on networking gear for the right solution.

Comment: I have a few of these usb to HDMI adapters and they work great. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SJQG4BF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: You have a MacBook on that diagram. Current MacBooks support USB-C HDMI dongles, and older MacBooks support Mini DisplayPort to HDMI dongles. So you can probably fo this with HDMI if you wanted to. The cost of two dongles is less than your $200 budget limit.

Comment: FYI, HDMI is designed for uncompressed hi-def video/graphics, so it is very high bandwidth. The current version is 48Gbps (!!), and even the original 1.0 version from 2002 is 5Gbps. It takes expensive equipment to do that kind of bandwidth over twisted-pair copper at a distance of more than say 2m. You may end up with price-vs-image-quality tradeoffs, where some products that send "HDMI" signals over UTP at more than ~2m distance do so by employing lossy compression (e.g. H.264 AVC, H.265 HEVC) to greatly reduce the bandwidth requirements. This may noticeably reduce the image quality.

Comment: From your diagram it looks like you're trying to achieve more than what your question actually details. So, if it's just a case of connecting the MacBook to two TVs, then buy the appropriate adaptors and connect it to your TVs. However, if you're trying to do *more* than this (which is what your diagram implies), you really need to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1500424/edit) your post to clarify that and provide more context.